# JW Player Not Loading on Mapped Domain

Tags: heroku, dns, jwplayer, domain-mapping

I created a site which I'm running through Heroku and everything is working fine on the app URL:
https://serene-scrubland-3140.herokuapp.com/

I then mapped the app to a custom domain:
http://www.wmpmedia.ca/

On the custom domain the JW player no longer loads at all. I've been through the code a couple times and figure the script is not getting a chance to load. I'm a bit new to this so any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are self hosting, and using the cloud hosted player, at the same time.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
```

And

```
<script src="http://jwpsrv.com/library/J13GIpn+EeSalhJtO5t17w.js"></script>
```

Try to remove one of the lines, you shouldn't use it twice. Try to remove the first, if that doesn't work, try to remove the 2nd, and use the first instead.

Comment: I just tested your setup locally and I see the issue. Your self hosted JW Player is 6.10. Your cloud hosted player is up to date though, and using 6.12, so the issue is that running 6.10 and 6.12 at the same time is creating a conflict. Just remove the self hosted parts, and leave the cloud hosted one there (or remove the cloud hosted line). I can confirm that doing either of these things fixes it. Odd it even worked on one of your sites, as it broke locally for me on a local xampp server!